# Is there a more elegant way to write this oracle sql conversion to t-sql which can improve the query performance for the view?

Tags: t-sql, case, oracle-sqldeveloper, subquery

Understanding that the `DECODE` statement is a `CASE` statement whereby (if there is a txt_value, there is no flg_value and vice-versa (a `COALESCE` with a where conditions, then append said value). Understand that the base table is poorly structured and cannont be changed.

The view in Oracle SQL is:

```
( P_ACTIVITIES.DISTRICT_CODE ) ||' ' ||  ( P_ACTIVITIES.WORK_REQUEST_NUMBER ) ""Activity"",
  P_ACTIVITIES.PROCESS_CODE ""ProcessNumber"",
  P_ACTIVITIES.CURRENT_ACTIVITY_STATUS_CODE ""Status"",
  P_ACTIVITIES.INITIAL_ACTIVITY_CODE ""InitialActivityCode"",
  P_ACTIVITIES.CURRENT_ACTIVITY_CODE ""CurrentActivityCode"",
  P_ACTIVITY_CODES.ACTIVITY_CODE_DESCRIPTION ""ActivityDescription"",
  (P_ACTIVITIES.RAISED_DATE_TIME) ""RaisedDate"",
  P_ACTIVITIES.COMPLETED_DATE_TIME ""CompletedDate"",
  P_ACTIVITIES.HOUSE_NUMBER_NAME ""HouseNameNumber"",
  P_ACTIVITIES.STREET_NAME ""Street"",
  P_ACTIVITIES.TOWN ""Town"",
  P_ACTIVITIES.POSTCODE ""Postcode"",
  P_ACTIVITIES.COMMENTS ""Comments"",
  INM_ACTIVITIES.GRID_REFERENCE_POINT ""GridReference"",
t.*
FROM
  P_TIME_PERIODS  TP_RaisedDate,
  P_DCF_ACTIVITY,
  INM_ACTIVITIES,
  P_FINANCE_GROUPS,
  P_CREW_HQS,
  P_ACTIVITY_CODES,
  P_ACTIVITIES,
  (SELECT
  DISTINCT
  M_WW_TWRKAE00.CDE_dist,
  M_WW_TWRKAE00.CDE_WR,

(SELECT DECODE(a.TXT_VALUE,NULL,a.FLG_VALUE,a.TXT_VALUE)  FROM M_WW_TWRKAE00  a WHERE M_WW_TWRKAE00.cde_dist=a.cde_dist AND M_WW_TWRKAE00.cde_wr=a.cde_wr AND a.CDE_ATTRIBUTE='E501') ""SewerPurpose"",
(SELECT DECODE(a.TXT_VALUE,NULL,a.FLG_VALUE,a.TXT_VALUE)  FROM M_WW_TWRKAE00  a WHERE M_WW_TWRKAE00.cde_dist=a.cde_dist AND M_WW_TWRKAE00.cde_wr=a.cde_wr AND a.CDE_ATTRIBUTE='E502') ""DepthToInvert"",
(SELECT DECODE(a.TXT_VALUE,NULL,a.FLG_VALUE,a.TXT_VALUE)  FROM M_WW_TWRKAE00  a WHERE M_WW_TWRKAE00.cde_dist=a.cde_dist AND M_WW_TWRKAE00.cde_wr=a.cde_wr AND a.CDE_ATTRIBUTE='E503') ""Maintainer"",
(SELECT DECODE(a.TXT_VALUE,NULL,a.FLG_VALUE,a.TXT_VALUE)  FROM M_WW_TWRKAE00  a WHERE M_WW_TWRKAE00.cde_dist=a.cde_dist AND M_WW_TWRKAE00.cde_wr=a.cde_wr AND a.CDE_ATTRIBUTE='E504') ""Diameter"",
(SELECT DECODE(a.TXT_VALUE,NULL,a.FLG_VALUE,a.TXT_VALUE)  FROM M_WW_TWRKAE00  a WHERE M_WW_TWRKAE00.cde_dist=a.cde_dist AND M_WW_TWRKAE00.cde_wr=a.cde_wr AND a.CDE_ATTRIBUTE='E505') ""CauseOfBlockage"",
(SELECT DECODE(a.TXT_VALUE,NULL,a.FLG_VALUE,a.TXT_VALUE)  FROM M_WW_TWRKAE00  a WHERE M_WW_TWRKAE00.cde_dist=a.cde_dist AND M_WW_TWRKAE00.cde_wr=a.cde_wr AND a.CDE_ATTRIBUTE='E507') ""Location"",
(SELECT DECODE(a.TXT_VALUE,NULL,a.FLG_VALUE,a.TXT_VALUE)  FROM M_WW_TWRKAE00  a WHERE M_WW_TWRKAE00.cde_dist=a.cde_dist AND M_WW_TWRKAE00.cde_wr=a.cde_wr AND a.CDE_ATTRIBUTE='E508') ""RisingMain"",
(SELECT DECODE(a.TXT_VALUE,NULL,a.FLG_VALUE,a.TXT_VALUE)  FROM M_WW_TWRKAE00  a WHERE M_WW_TWRKAE00.cde_dist=a.cde_dist AND M_WW_TWRKAE00.cde_wr=a.cde_wr AND a.CDE_ATTRIBUTE='E509') ""ClearanceMethod"",
(SELECT DECODE(a.TXT_VALUE,NULL,a.FLG_VALUE,a.TXT_VALUE)  FROM M_WW_TWRKAE00  a WHERE M_WW_TWRKAE00.cde_dist=a.cde_dist AND M_WW_TWRKAE00.cde_wr=a.cde_wr AND a.CDE_ATTRIBUTE='E510') ""MinorCleanUp"",
(SELECT DECODE(a.TXT_VALUE,NULL,a.FLG_VALUE,a.TXT_VALUE)  FROM M_WW_TWRKAE00  a WHERE M_WW_TWRKAE00.cde_dist=a.cde_dist AND M_WW_TWRKAE00.cde_wr=a.cde_wr AND a.CDE_ATTRIBUTE='E511') ""MHCondition"",
(SELECT DECODE(a.TXT_VALUE,NULL,a.FLG_VALUE,a.TXT_VALUE)  FROM M_WW_TWRKAE00  a WHERE M_WW_TWRKAE00.cde_dist=a.cde_dist AND M_WW_TWRKAE00.cde_wr=a.cde_wr AND a.CDE_ATTRIBUTE='E512') ""BlockageAtIC"",
(SELECT DECODE(a.TXT_VALUE,NULL,a.FLG_VALUE,a.TXT_VALUE)  FROM M_WW_TWRKAE00  a WHERE M_WW_TWRKAE00.cde_dist=a.cde_dist AND M_WW_TWRKAE00.cde_wr=a.cde_wr AND a.CDE_ATTRIBUTE='E514') ""UpstreamMH"",
(SELECT DECODE(a.TXT_VALUE,NULL,a.FLG_VALUE,a.TXT_VALUE)  FROM M_WW_TWRKAE00  a WHERE M_WW_TWRKAE00.cde_dist=a.cde_dist AND M_WW_TWRKAE00.cde_wr=a.cde_wr AND a.CDE_ATTRIBUTE='E515') ""DownstreamMH"",
(SELECT DECODE(a.TXT_VALUE,NULL,a.FLG_VALUE,a.TXT_VALUE)  FROM M_WW_TWRKAE00  a WHERE M_WW_TWRKAE00.cde_dist=a.cde_dist AND M_WW_TWRKAE00.cde_wr=a.cde_wr AND a.CDE_ATTRIBUTE='E516') ""Material"",
(SELECT DECODE(a.TXT_VALUE,NULL,a.FLG_VALUE,a.TXT_VALUE)  FROM M_WW_TWRKAE00  a WHERE M_WW_TWRKAE00.cde_dist=a.cde_dist AND M_WW_TWRKAE00.cde_wr=a.cde_wr AND a.CDE_ATTRIBUTE='E517') ""NearWatercourse"",
(SELECT DECODE(a.TXT_VALUE,NULL,a.FLG_VALUE,a.TXT_VALUE)  FROM M_WW_TWRKAE00  a WHERE M_WW_TWRKAE00.cde_dist=a.cde_dist AND M_WW_TWRKAE00.cde_wr=a.cde_wr AND a.CDE_ATTRIBUTE='E518') ""IncerceptorRemoved"",
(SELECT DECODE(a.TXT_VALUE,NULL,a.FLG_VALUE,a.TXT_VALUE)  FROM M_WW_TWRKAE00  a WHERE M_WW_TWRKAE00.cde_dist=a.cde_dist AND M_WW_TWRKAE00.cde_wr=a.cde_wr AND a.CDE_ATTRIBUTE='E513') ""AssetOnGIS""
FROM
  M_WW_TWRKAE00 ,
  M_WW_DCF_LOOKUP
WHERE
  ( M_WW_TWRKAE00.CDE_ATTRIBUTE=M_WW_DCF_LOOKUP.ATTRIBUTE_CODE  )
  AND  ( M_WW_DCF_LOOKUP.DCF_SCREEN_DESC in ('Blockages' ,'Flooding Investigation' ))) t
WHERE
      (t.cde_dist(+)=P_ACTIVITIES.district_code AND t.cde_wr(+)=P_ACTIVITIES.work_request_number)
 AND  ( P_ACTIVITY_CODES.ACTIVITY_CODE(+)=P_ACTIVITIES.CURRENT_ACTIVITY_CODE  )
  AND  ( P_ACTIVITIES.FINANCE_GROUP_CODE=P_FINANCE_GROUPS.FINANCE_GROUP_CODE(+)  )
  AND  ( P_CREW_HQS.CREW_HQ_CODE(+)=P_ACTIVITIES.CREW_HQ_CODE  )
  AND  ( TP_RaisedDate.PERIOD_LEVEL='day' AND TP_RaisedDate.PERIOD_START_DATE=TRUNC(P_ACTIVITIES.COMPLETED_DATE_TIME)  )
  AND  ( P_ACTIVITIES.DISTRICT_CODE=P_DCF_ACTIVITY.CDE_DIST AND P_ACTIVITIES.WORK_REQUEST_NUMBER=P_DCF_ACTIVITY.CDE_WR  )
  AND  ( P_ACTIVITIES.DISTRICT_CODE=INM_ACTIVITIES.DISTRICT_CODE(+) AND P_ACTIVITIES.WORK_REQUEST_NUMBER=INM_ACTIVITIES.WORK_REQUEST_NUMBER(+)  )
  AND  (
  P_ACTIVITIES.CURRENT_ACTIVITY_CODE  IN ('SDBPR','SDBPU','XSDBPU','SDBPUX')
  AND  TRUNC(P_ACTIVITIES.RAISED_DATE_TIME)  >=  TRUNC(to_date(to_char(sysdate - 1, 'DD-MM-RR')||' 23:59','DD-MM-RR HH24:mi')-29)
  )
```

How could one convert this to T-SQL language for optimal query performance?

Comment: What is your actual end question here, as you don't appear to ask anything specific. Also, T-SQL doesn't support `Case` (`Switch`) statements, only `CASE` expressions.

Comment: @Larnu how to convert the query to T-SQL?

Comment: Side note, as well, it long time you stopped using that old ANSI-89 syntax. You should have switched to the ANSI-92 explicit syntax years ago; it was introduced 29 years ago so you've had plenty of time by now.

Comment: If you're 2 months into SQL, I'm honestly confused as to why you learned the 32 year old syntax, when it was superseded some 29 years ago. ;) Explicit syntax is a must for both readable and scalable SQL. Especially when a lot of recent versions of RDBMS' don't support anything other than implicit `INNER JOIN`s any more. SQL Server for example, removed support for implicit `LEFT JOIN`s in 2012. [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: @Lamu. It's a database migration to cloud (Azure).